# Call method on object in try-with-resources block

Tags: java, prepared-statement, try-with-resources, autocloseable

The [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) state that you can do the following with `try-with-resources`:

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

In this tutorial the `ResultSet` is never closed, thus I want to include the `ResultSet` , as it also implements the `AutoCloseable` interface, like so:

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

This works fine, but when it comes to `PreparedStatements` I want to be able to set some values on the *before* executing the query:

```
String name = "Ian";
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = getPreparedStatement(con, stmt); 
     pstmt.setString(1, name);
     ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

This causes a range of compilation errors, because (I am assuming) only variable assignment is allowed.

Is there anyway to do this neatly in the same `try-with-resources` block?

I have already thought of:

1. Nested try-with-resources (which is what I am trying to avoid). I realise there is nothing 'wrong' with doing so, I merely want to do this for the sake of readability.

Consider the following to cases:

```
try (MyObject1 o1 = new MyObject1()) {
    o1.setSomeValue();
    try (MyObject2 o2 = new MyObject2(o1)) {
        o2.setSomeValue();
        try (MyObject3 o3 = new MyObeject3(o2) {
            o3.setSomeValue();
            // do work here
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

vs

```
try (MyObject1 o1 = new MyObject1();
     o1.setSomeValue();
     MyObject3 o2 = new MyObeject2(o1);
     o2.setSomeValue();
     MyObject3 o3 = new MyObeject3(o2);
     o3.setSomeValue()) {

    // do work here
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

2. Having `setString()` method return the object and include it in assignment
3. Creating some sort of helper method that creates the connection and sets parameters accordingly.

Something like:

```
public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con, String stmt, Object ... params) {

}
```

Comment: You could use a nested `try` without a `catch`. This would close the `ResultSet` and any occuring exception would be handled by the outer catch block.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you meant `Connection.prepareStatement()`.

There is no need to close the ResultSet explicitely, since API-Doc of `Statement.close` guarantees to close its ResultSet. So it's fine to write

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ...
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah! This does actually solve the problem I am facing (and that of my example) but this is not sufficient to answer the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set some value between constructing the `Statement` and the `ResultSet` you will need nested try-with-resources blocks. Why are you trying to avoid that? There's nothing wrong with doing so.

You could define some unwieldy number of helper methods, but except for a few very high-usage cases this will be much more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I understand that there is nothing wrong with it. I have update my answer to explain why I want to avoid nested blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can like this:

```
try (
     Connection con = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
     PreparedStatement ps = TryJumper.jump(con.prepareStatement("select * from x where a = ?"), pss -> {
         pss.setInt(1, 123);
     });
     ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
) {
    //core codes
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Necessary class

```
public class TryJumper {

    public static <M> M jump(M m, MUser<M> mUser) throws Exception {
        mUser.consume(m);
        return m;
    }

    interface MUser<M> extends AutoCloseable {
        void consume(M m) throws Exception;

        @Override
        default void close() throws Exception {
        }
    }

}
```

How is it work:

In try catch resources everything should return an `Object` which implement from `AutoClosable` interface. This class simply returning same object which you pass after your consume method work (in `lambda`)